# Running shell script using NSTask in Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shell, networking, nstask

I have written a shell script and the purpose of that script is to capture packet using TCPDUMP and write that capture packet to .pcap file

**Script is: TCPDumpScript.sh**

**echo "peter" | sudo -S tcpdump -i rv0 -n -s 0 -w dumpfile.pcap tcp**

I am launching (TCPDumpScript.sh) using NSTask. Getting following output

*tcpdump: WARNING: rv0: That device doesn't support promiscuous mode
(BIOCPROMISC: Operation not supported on socket)
tcpdump: WARNING: rv0: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on rv0, link-type PKTAP (Packet Tap), capture size 65535 bytes*

**Problem 1:** 
Using NSTask. "dumpfile.pcap" is being created.
but when I run the same script using Terminal, its being created with desired captured packets.

**Problem 2:** 
Whenever making changes in **TCPDumpScript.sh** and then launching script using NSTask. I am getting following error
**"launch path not accessible"**

But I do via terminal
**chmod +x TCPDumpScript.sh**

Then I am able to launch this script without any error using NSTask.

**So, my question is Can't I create file (Problem 1) "dumpfile.pcap" using NSTask ?
And Do I always require to run permission change command on script file (Problem 2) ?**

Please guide me.

- (void)runScript:(NSArray*)arguments {

  dispatch_queue_t taskQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
  dispatch_async(taskQueue, ^{

  ```
  self.isRunning = YES;

  @try {

      NSString *path  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TcpDumpScript" ofType:@"sh"]];         
      self.buildTask            = [[NSTask alloc] init];
      self.buildTask.launchPath = path;
      self.buildTask.arguments  = arguments;

      // Output Handling
      self.outputPipe               = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
      self.buildTask.standardOutput = self.outputPipe;

      [[self.outputPipe fileHandleForReading] waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:[self.outputPipe fileHandleForReading] queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){

          NSData *output = [[self.outputPipe fileHandleForReading] availableData];
          NSString *outStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

          dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              self.outPutTxt.string = [self.outPutTxt.string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@", outStr]];
              // Scroll to end of outputText field
              NSRange range;
              range = NSMakeRange([self.outPutTxt.string length], 0);
              [self.outPutTxt scrollRangeToVisible:range];
          });

          [[self.outputPipe fileHandleForReading] waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
      }];

      [self.buildTask launch];

      [self.buildTask waitUntilExit];
  }
  @catch (NSException *exception) {
      NSLog(@"Problem Running Task: %@", [exception description]);
  }
  @finally {
      [self.Start setEnabled:YES];
      [self.spinner stopAnimation:self];
      self.isRunning = NO;
  }
  ```

  });
  }

Comment: Show the code for the `NSTask` - how are you setting the current directory and environment? What permissions are required for the created file?

Comment: @Wain: How to set current directory and environment ?
created file will be used for reading only.
I used NSTask first time.So, I may be missing something. please suggest me.

Comment: issue resolved. Followed following steps 

Xcode->Editor->Add Build Phase->Add Run script Build Phase

in Run Script added following lines
chmod +x ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/appName.app/Resources/TcpDumpScript.sh

Things are working fine now :).